# raspberry pi camera reduce capturing time

Tags: python, performance, camera, raspberry-pi, subprocess

I am working on a program on raspberry pi b+ model, i needs to capture images from a raspberry pi camera, i used this code to capture images:

```
cmd='raspistill -o photo.jpg -t 20 -ex auto -awb auto -w 760 -h 890 -n'
pid=subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
```

or

```
camera.capture()
```

this code is take about 1.3 sec to capture and save image to SD card.

The question: can  i reduce this time or store the image in parameter not to SD card

Comment: What about posting this question in the raspberrypi-stackexchange-forum?

Comment: there is more than 100 question but no answers

Comment: *"or store the image in parameter"* -- it is a different question (from the question about performance) -- if you want to get the image as a bytestring; check whether `raspistill` can write image to stdout instead of a file e.g., try `-o -` command-line parameter and use `image = subprocess.check_output()`. Unrelated: drop `shell=True` and add `.split()` after the literal.